# How do I get the value from a MdListOption element?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm having a lot of difficulty trying to use Angular Material, specifically with regards to the Selection List. I am displaying a list of objects in a Angular Material Selection List and I want to get the objects from the list of selected items.

This is what I have so far, but `[value]="row"` just gives me `true` when I call `rows.selectedOptions.selected[0].value`:

```js
submit(rows) {
    console.log(rows);
    console.log(rows.selectedOptions.selected[0].value);
    console.log(rows.selectedOptions.selected[0]._getHostElement().innerText); // ugly hack, but at least it gives me the text of the option
}
```

```html
<md-selection-list #rows dense>
  <md-list-option *ngFor="let row of config.data" [value]="row">
    {{row.title}}
  </md-list-option>
</md-selection-list>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="p-2">
    <button md-button (click)="submit(rows)">
      <span>Submit</span>
      <md-icon aria-label="submit">arrow_forward</md-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the actual `row` from the list of selected options?

Comment: But doesn't `rows.selectedOptions.selected[0].value` returns the object already? If you want the title that would be `rows.selectedOptions.selected[0].value.title`. Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the API documentation : https://material.angular.io/components/list/api

> @Output() selectChange :
>   Emitted when the option is selected.

so I guess using

```
<md-selection-list #rows dense>
  <md-list-option *ngFor="let row of config.data" (selectChange)="onSelectOptionChange($event)">
    {{row.title}}
  </md-list-option>
</md-selection-list>
```

will give you the data you want in your TypeScript side :

```
onSelectOptionChange(value: any) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Not tested, but that should work. (**NO IT DOESN'T**)

**EDIT :** I've been doing some testing in a plunkr, and here are my results :

*Provided Plunkr for free laughters :* https://plnkr.co/edit/1G3bgJ2Twue0RH7CGmK2?p=preview

I've been using the same code you provided :

```
<md-selection-list #rows dense>
  <md-list-option *ngFor="let row of config.data" 
  (selectChange)="onSelectChange($event)"
  (deselected)="onDeselected($event)"
  [checkboxPosition]="after"
  [value]="[testValue]" 
  [selected]="[testValue]">
    {{row.title}}
  </md-list-option>
</md-selection-list>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="p-2">
    <button md-button (click)="submit(rows)"> 
      <span>Submit</span>
      <md-icon aria-label="submit">arrow_forward</md-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the TypeScript I used for my tests

```
export class App {
  testValue: true;

  config = {
    data: [
      {
        title: 'Title1',
      },
      {
        title: 'Title2',
      },
      {
        title: 'Title3',
      },
      {
        title: 'Title4',
      }
    ]
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  onDeselected(value: any) {
    console.log('deselected event => ', value);
  }

  onSelectChange(value: any) {
    console.log('change => ', value);  
  }

  submit(rows) {
    console.log(rows.selectedOptions.selected.map(elements => {
      return elements._getHostElement().innerText;
    }));
  }
}
```

And the results :

- Setting the `value` through an input is useless : it does set a value to  the option-list-item which is not used for anything.
- Setting the `selected` through an input is somewhat useless : It works when rendering, but here in the example I set them to `true`, and if I submit instantly, I get no result (`rows.selectedOptions.selected` is an empty array).
- The `selectChange` Output event doesn't work.
- The `deselected` Output event doesn't work.
- I couldn't find any other way than you did to get the Option title simply. This is what I used to get it in an array (guess it's more practical) : `console.log(rows.selectedOptions.selected.map(elements => {
    return elements._getHostElement().innerText;
  }));`
- > @Input() checkboxPosition : Whether the label should appear before or after the checkbox. Defaults to 'after'. **No, it defaults to 'before' !**

> How can I get the actual `row` from the list of selected options?

**Conclusion :** You can't and this component is utter garbage : **Do not use it...**

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I'm looking for. I've looked at the documentation, but it doesn't seem to have what I need as far as I can tell. I thought there might be something not shown that I could use, but I guess that's unlikely.

Comment: What does `console.log(rows.selectedOptions.selected)` displays ?

Comment: That gives me an array of `MdListOption`, but the values and methods on that object do not seem to help me at all. Can't even get the index of the `MdListOption` in the complete list of options.

Comment: Can you edit and add the object you wanna pass ? I'm doing some tests currently

Comment: Edited the answer. Just drop this component, it's not worth your time.

Comment: Thanks for doing all that work. I was afraid we would come to this conclusion, but I just don't think it's ready for production :/

Comment: It's tilting that they even try to set the documentation while nothing work on their component, really...
Did my best, good luck for you now :-)

Comment: this is still WIP. See this [PR](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/7456) and wait a bit :-)

Answer (score 2):

you could handle it with something like:

in your component.ts:

```
rows: Array<string> = []; //explicitly define and init property here

toggleRow(value:string){
    if(this.rows.indexOf(value) !== -1){
      this.rows.splice(this.rows.indexOf(value), 1);
    }else{
      this.rows.push(value);    
    }
}
submit(rows) {
  console.log(rows);
}
```

and your component.html:

```
<md-selection-list #rows dense>
  <md-list-option *ngFor="let row of config.data" (click)="toggleRow(row.title)">
    {{row.title}}
  </md-list-option>
</md-selection-list>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="p-2">
    <button md-button (click)="submit(rows)">
      <span>Submit</span>
      <md-icon aria-label="submit">arrow_forward</md-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

you could also use an `Array<any>` or similar and `.push()` the entire `row` object into your `rows` array (instead of just the `.title`)...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with not being able to extract value from MdListOption.
I ended up using the workaround that kind of defeats the purpose, but still:

```
<md-selection-list #rows dense>
  <md-list-option *ngFor="let row of config.data" (click)="clickedOnRow(row)">
    {{row.title}}
  </md-list-option>
</md-selection-list>
```

and then keeping track of my selections in the clickedOnRow() in the component.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in angular 5 .I ended up using SelectionModel and bind a click event

```
<mat-selection-list #AnswerableBaseline>
     <mat-list-option *ngFor="let a of dataSourceForAnswerable" (click)="onAnswerableBaselineListClicked(a)" checkboxPosition="before">
     </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**ts file**

```
selectionBaseline   = new SelectionModel<Your Type>(true, []);
onAnswerableBaselineListClicked(row: any) {        
    if (!this.selectionBaseline.isSelected(row)) {
        this.selectionBaseline.select(row);
    }
    else {
        this.selectionBaseline.deselect(row);
    }

}
```